# Different variable types in the SAME ARRAY? (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The program I am creating a program in which a method is using ***A LOT*** of different arrays! For me, it is rather difficult to keep track of *all* them. So, why not combine them into a multi-dimensional array? My problem is how can I combine a `String[]` array with a `Object[]` array?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you specify? Think of a 2D array as a matrix. What cells do you want as stings and which as objects?

Comment: Also, if you're combining arrays just to make them easier to keep track of, I am not sure it's a great design plan.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? Why are you combining arrays into a multi-dimensional array if they're not related? What do you want your end result to be?

Comment: Using multidimensional arrays in my opinion would make it more confusing for someone reading your code. You may be best of using an ArrayList with generics which are type safe.

Comment: The reason I am asking this question is because I am making a program in which the user can specify where panels are, what Layout to use... I want all the data for JPanel to be in 1 array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare an array of a particular type, all subtypes can be stored in the array. E.g.

```
  Object myArray[];
```

can now store any object, Strings, Dates, JButtons etc. However, this can be dangerous when you are retrieving the items from the array. You have to ensure that you interpret them correctly. The compiler would not be able to warn you if you store the wrong type of object in there.

A better approach might be to create your own collection object that stores all the various items in a way that is type safe.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like your missing an abstraction, if all your arrays are the same length there is probably a class that you should be defining; a record type data structure that either has all public fields (if your data should be immutable add **final**) or a JavaBean with getters and setters.
Lots of arrays of primitives values is very procedural, Java is an Object orientated language so use this in your design.

To add to @styfle's comment; if they're unrelated why would you want to do this?  And if they're related why aren't you defining classes?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an `ArrayList<Superclass[]>` where superclass is some class from which everything you're using inherits. If there is no such class, then use Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object[ ][ ], as String are objects.

Answer (score -2):

Why not using one `Object` and put all your arrays in it.

Comment: Not a good idea. You would need to cast back and forth which could introduce ClassCastExceptions into the code at runtime.